# I wrote a code in HTML. IE is not rendering it properly

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have been working on a piece of HTML code for some personal use.

The code works perfectly fine in Chrome(38.0.2125.111 m), Firefox(32.0.3) and Opera(24.0.1558.53) on my Windows 8.1 machine. Since it is on a local server, I managed to test it on other machine too. But my IE11(11.0.9600.17416) is not working well with the code.

Here is the code I have written:

```
<section class="gs">
    <input id="googleSearch" class="googleSearch" type="text" name="search" autocomplete="off" />
    <div id="resultGS" class="result"></div>
</section>
```

Here is the code IE has rendered:

```
<section class=gs></section>
    <input id=googleSearch class=googleSearch name=search autocomplete="off"></input>
    <div id=resultGS class=result></div>
</section><//section>
```

Can anyone please explain me what is going on here?Anyone has any ideas?

Here is the snapshot of the code:

[image]

As far as I can see IE is completing tags by itself as it has done with the input tag, am I correct?

Comment: "IE is not rendering it properly" Tell me something new...
Also you have two slashes on the closing tag for your last `section`

Comment: @Kroltan the second code block the OP shows is the code that was generated by IE.

Comment: What compatibility mode is IE using to display your page ?

Comment: Looks like the same issue that was present in 6, 7 and 8: https://blog.whatwg.org/supporting-new-elements-in-ie

Comment: @t.niese Oh, sorry. I jut thought that the OP had typed in the IE generated markup and had a typo on it. I was on my mobile with images off and didn't see the screencap, sorry.

Comment: @Kroltan You said it right its nothing new about IE not rendering properly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the question describes is not document rendering at all, but the way IE shows HTML code in it developer tools, in a particular state. You see the code that way when you press F12 and then select the “DOM Explorer” tab.

And this is not normal in IE 11. It only appears when the browser has been set to emulate IE 8 or lower, in the first dropdown in the “Emulation” tab in the dev tools. Simply select “Edge” there.

When you are using IE 11 in IE 8 or lower mode, or when someone is actually using IE 8 or lower, the browser does not actually support `section` *at all*. It behaves as if the tags were not there, simply rendering the content between them. (The code display in dev tools reflects this, in its odd way.) This normally affects only *styling*. The `section` element has no default effect beyond being rendered as a block, and normally its content is blocks anyway, so even this does not matter. But supports matter if you try to style `section`, of course.

If you really need to use IE 8, simulated or real, the following code before any CSS references fixes the issue by “introducing” the element to the browser:

```
<script>
document.createElement('section');
</script>
```

(This does not seem to work when emulating IE 7 or lower, but this is probably a bug in the emulation. It should work, in the sense of making the element styleable, on IE versions down to 6.)

Comment: What u said did work. but only temporarily. How do I retain that setting? I searched on internet and Microsoft website, but nothing good.

Comment: As for the "flaw in my question", I said "not working _properly/well_".Not just "not working". :P :D

Comment: @user3787724, can you post an example of a complete (preferably minimal) document, perhaps with HTTP headers, which makes IE 11 use IE 8 or lower emulation mode?

Comment: will a screenshot do? Mine uses IE7 emulation as default mode. Also my code is created purely for fun, ofcourse I needed it but don't mind sharing it. Will that do? If you say yes, I'll zip HTML,CSS and screenshot & uploaded it to some cloud.

Comment: No, a question should contain minimal *code* that lets anyone reconstruct the problem for inspection. Minimal means that it should contain code that suffices to generate the problem, and nothing more.  This could mean just a few lines of HTML plus the HTTP headers. You should also describe what is the problem in *page rendering* rather than just in looking at the code (DOM).

Answer (score 1):

As Claudix said, adding the HTML5 doctype should help. Because it will set the IE browser to the last compatibility mode.
But for some reason (IE settings, intranet,...), it can be forced to use a specific mode. If this is the case, add a meta to force IE to execute your page with the most recent compatibility mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Is there a difference in how CSS works for html 4 and html 5? I am seeing some(specially for text input element) after changing _<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>_ to _<!DOCTYPE html>_

Comment: Also, it did not work. @jukka-k-korpela has suggested something in one of the answers which worked partly. But it by default loads into 7 compatibility rather than edge compatibility. So its not a permanent solution

Answer (score 0):

The `<section>` tag is new in HTML5. Have you put the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the top of the HTML file (before the `<html>` tag)?

Comment: This won't correct the rendering error if the user's testing locally (as the OP is) because IE renders local files in compatibility mode unless you tell it not to with "IE=Edge".

Comment: Not sure about that... I'm using the same IE version as the OP and the <DOCTYPE> declaration seems enough for me, even in local files :/

Comment: You can also turn it off as a setting in IE itself, it's possible you've done that? IE definitley does the compatability thing with local files unless you tell it not to.

Comment: Nope... Actually I have explicitly enabled "intranet files" to be rendered in compatibility mode as well as I added explicit URLs to be rendered the same way. I've also checked my local server is not sending the X-UA-Compatible header neither.

Comment: Compatibility/Quirks mode does *not* affect things like support to `section`.

Comment: Yes I have put _<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>_ . And I also tried _<!DOCTYPE html>_ for the sake of IE